# How to change scrollbar colour in QScrollarea using with pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a scroll area in my program, i changed my back ground colour of the scroll area is black,so my scrollbar is not visible because of the background colour.Please tell me  how can i change the style sheet of the scrollbar.I tried given code but it is not worked for me

Given bellow is my sample code:

```
self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet('QScrollArea {background-color : #000000;border:none}')
scrollbar = """QScrollBar:vertical {
                        background:white;
                        width: 100px;
                        margin: 45px 0 45px 0;
                      }
"""
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the scrollbar using

```
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical,QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
        background: <color>;
    }
```

Comment: Its not changing i got  the same